# Detecting the index of datagrid row affected by change in dataprovider(array collection)

Tags: apache-flex

I have an array collection as the dataprovider to a datagrid. When I change a value in the arraycollection, a particular row gets updated in the datagrid. I want to get the index of that particular row. How do I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store the datagrid's current dataprovider in a temp variable and then compare it with the new dataprovider. Make sure that the temp variable isnt bindable.